# Image showing in preview but not on Android tablet. XML issue?

Tags: android, xml, image, preview

So I have been working on an Android application to make an application for use with DJI's consumer level drones. I have been making the user interface and using XML throughout the project with no issues. I want to add a .png to the UI just so that my logo is showing. When I preview it in Android Studio, I can see the logo being shown but when it is run on the tablet, it is not there. Everything else using XML is fine though. I even preview using the same resolution/ screen size as my tablet I am using (cheap Hudl 2 tablet).

If anybody has any ideas about how I can get this to work, I would appreciate it. I have shown my university lecturer it and he couldn't give me an answer too as nothing seems to be out of the ordinary.

[Android studio preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsMFZ.png)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/macrosfordji"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: You'r using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/macrosfordji"` so must be sure you have added  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace to parent layout.

Comment: I have used that... Still no luck

Comment: In which directory is your drawable? What is the Android version of the tablet? Is your drawable a PNJ file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (android:src="..." instead app:srcCompat="..."):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/macrosfordji"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```